# How to disable widescreen video in Skype?

Tags: video, skype

Since the latest (forced) update, Skype insists on displaying my video in widescreen (16:9) format. The problem with this is that it has a lower vertical resolution: in the old 4:3 mode, the video comfortably showed my whole face when I had my laptop on the table whereas in the new 16:9 one it just shows a "stripe" with the top and bottom cut off.

Is there a way to disable 16:9 output? It's a Dell XPS with built-in camera and I'd be willing to adjust the camera settings too, but neither Skype nor the camera software seem to have a "force 4:3 output" option.